# How to make AWS ElasticBeanstalk build npm packages for the front-end?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install

I'm building a project with Python (Flask) backend and React frontend. What I did:

1. Set NPM_USE_PRODUCTION to true on AWS instance
2. package.json has this lines:

   ```
    "scripts": {
        "prestart": "npm install",
        "start": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js" },
   ```

But it still doesn't install packages and doesn't build bundles. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That's gonna take longer to deploy specially if you have a lot of instances. Better to just build it in your local and run eb deploy.

Comment: I'm okay to wait. I don't have a lot of instances. Hot to do that?